# Error enabling soapclient for wordpress, php7 on amazon webservices ec2 rds

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yum, php-7

I used CloudFormation to install WordPress on EC2 and RDS. I had to upgrade to PHP 7, but I needed to enable a SOAP client for WordPress. I tried to enable using:

```
php -i | grep -i soap    
yum search php | grep -i soap    
sudo yum install php-soap
```

but received the following errors:

```
error:  php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
error:  php70-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
```

Is it because the old `php-common` 5.3.29 is still there?  If so, how can I remove and install new `php70`, or enable the SOAP client which is my goal?

I used `php -v` to check my PHP version, and it is PHP 7.0.14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because the `php-soap` package depends on php5, not php7. You need to find/use a package of php-soap that depends on the PHP7-based package you currently have installed (`php70w`). Perhaps the following command will work instead:

```
sudo yum install php70w-soap
```

Answer (score 0):

I fond this is worked! Thanks!

```
sudo yum install php70-soap.x86_64
```